# how to download file with blob function using angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

download any file type with blob function

```
private saveAsBlob(data: any) {
 const blob = new Blob([data._body],
 const file = new File([blob], 'image.png',
 FileSaver.saveAs(file);
}
```

Comment: You should mention that FileSaver is a non-native package available here: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/. Also --- this is not a real question as currently written.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

i got it like this it work with url:

```
download(row) {
    return this.Http
      .get(url, {
        responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob,
      })
      .map(res => {
        return {
          filename: row.name,
          data: res.blob()
        };
      })
      .subscribe(res => {
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(res.data);
        let a = document.createElement('a');
        document.body.appendChild(a);
        a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
        a.href = url;
        a.download = res.filename;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        a.remove();
      });
  }
```

Comment: why you are posting a new answer

Comment: createObjectURL is now deprecated in google chrome and isn't the Angular way to do things anyways.

Comment: @tatsu, So what is the "Angular way to do things"? maybe you can provide an alternative for people ending up here desperately looking for an proper answer to a simple problem.

Comment: Deprecated or not, as long as it works... And I do not see any deprecation notes on Mozilla: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

Comment: @tatsu 2021 and still no "angular" way to convert a blob to a usable file

Comment: what should have been clear from the above was that I was desperate as well, not that I had found a solution... (I was in an electron case, so I ended up useing the electron-dl lib)

Comment: to make this redundanly clear for future visist: there is no "angular way" to do this. so please don't listen to @tatsu - he doesn't provide an "angular way" solution either... sure you can wrap it somehow, but in the end this is exactly the code you will have to perform.

also: URL.createObjectURL is NOT deprecated. in fact it is the only possible solution to the asked task. and it is totally fine and up to date. what IS deprecated is the use of URL.createObjectURL in the context of media streams. it has been removed from the interface there for quite some time now. 

use this solution!

Answer (score 6):

Try the following code

```
saveAsBlob(data: Response){
  var blob = new Blob([data._body], { type: 'image/png' });
  var url= window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: As said above, createObjectURL is deprecated

Comment: @Moff452 I do not see it being deprecated on Mozzila https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL . Where do you get that information from?

Comment: URL.createObjectURL is NOT deprecated. in fact it is the only possible solution to the asked task. and it is totally fine and up to date. what IS deprecated is the use of URL.createObjectURL in the context of media streams. it has been removed from the interface there for quite some time now.

Answer (score 3):

My solution to start a download. I used this in an NgRX Effect.

```js
// ... getting blob form somewhere
const anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.download = "some_file_name.txt";
anchor.href = (window.webkitURL || window.URL).createObjectURL(blob);
anchor.click();
```